# Networkx specific nodes labeling

Tags: python, networkx

I want to draw a network and I want it to be unlabeled with the exception for cretin nodes.

What I have at the moment is something like this:

```
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, node_color='b', node_size=8, with_labels=False)

for hub in hubs:
     nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[hub[0]], node_color='r')
```

The code at the moment changes the size and color of the nodes in the hubs list. I'd like to label them as well.

I tried to add the label argument and set its value to the hub name. but it did't work.

Thanks

Comment: If `hubs` items are already in graph `G` you should call `nx.draw_networkx` with `labels` set to dictionary that have keys as hub nodes and values as labels/strings.

Comment: Actually what you said solves the problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From Bula's comment the solution is quite easy

The trick is to set the labels in a dictionary where the key is the node name and the value is the label you require. Therefore to label only the hubs, the code will be something similar to this:

```
labels = {}    
for node in G.nodes():
    if node in hubs:
        #set the node name as the key and the label as its value 
        labels[node] = node
#set the argument 'with labels' to False so you have unlabeled graph
nx.draw(G, with_labels=False)
#Now only add labels to the nodes you require (the hubs in my case)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels,font_size=16,font_color='r')
```

I got what I wanted which is the following:
[image]

I hope this would help other python/networkx newbies like myself :)

Again, Thanks Bula

Comment: Glad that it helped, this information was in [documentation](http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx) but the expression was not clear so to be on a safe side you can just experiment or look in `draw_networkx` [source line](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L262) where it calls `draw_networkx_labels` and [there](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L698) it iterates over dictionary making lables.