# Labeling nodes in a networkx graph when nodes are objects

Tags: python, networkx

It's easy to label the nodes of a graph using networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G1 = nx.Graph()
a = "A"
b = "B"
G1.add_nodes_from([a, b])
G1.add_edge(a, b)
nx.draw_networkx(G1) # default with_labels=True
plt.show()
```

[image: graph plot]

If the nodes are objects rather than strings, I understand that [it's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14667533/704972) to create an extra dictionary and use it for the node labels, but is it possible to use an object member (`name`) directly as the label?

```
class Breakfast:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

spam = Breakfast("Spam")
eggs = Breakfast("Eggs")
G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_nodes_from([spam, eggs])
G2.add_edge(spam, eggs)
nx.draw_networkx(G2, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's wrong with        G2.add_nodes_from([spam.name, eggs.name])
    G2.add_edge(spam.name, eggs.name)?

Comment: @MathBio The trouble is that the nodes are then the strings, not the Breakfast objects, and accessing the other attributes of a node object would require setting up an extra dictionary (and would restrict the names to be unique).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a simple `repr` method seems to do the trick:

```
class Breakfast:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

spam = Breakfast("Spam")
eggs = Breakfast("Eggs")
G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_nodes_from([spam, eggs])
G2.add_edge(spam, eggs)
nx.draw_networkx(G2, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: nodes as objects]

Comment: @Calaf Maybe try to increase the node size. I suggest `graph-tool` which uses cairo to draw. But I don't understand, why my answer does not answer your question?

Comment: It does. I was hoping you also know a solution to the node_shape problem. :)

Comment: I already answered a similar question. The only way I know is to actually look at the source code, and create your own matplotlib drawing function. Overall, if you want to draw graphs, I suggest you don't use matplotlib. Maybe some interactive JS stuff like [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/)

Comment: If both `__repr__` and `__str__` methods are used, networkx will use `__str__` method as label.